# Abstract Factory Pattern @Service in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm wondering how to use Abstract Factory Implementation class as a @Service inside my application.
I've have several providers of my wanted logic and injected them through the Constructor. The problem is I'm not sure weather my Factory should have the constructor and if it should, should it be private.

I have annotated this class as a @Service but was wondering if any of this is good and what are best practices.
Thank you and sorry if the upper is a mess, this is actually my first question and post.

Here is my code snippet:

```java
    private final FirstClient first;
    private final SecondClient second;

    private SentimentFactoryImpl(FirstClient first, SecondCliend second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public SentimentClient get(String clientName) {
        if ("First".equalsIgnoreCase(clientName)) {
            return this.first;
        } else if ("Second".equalsIgnoreCase(clientName)) {
            return this.second;
        } 
        throw new UnknownClientException("Service doesn't provide support for client: " + clientName);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the core of Spring framework is kind of super flexible and powerful abstract factory. If you are using Spring you should delegate all class creational functionality to Spring core. In your case I prefer to use Spring java `Configurations` for class creation. The equivalent of your factory in Spring will looks like that.

```java
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public SentimentClient firstClient() {
        return new FirstClient();
    }

    @Bean
    public SentimentClient secondClient() {
        return new SecondClient();
    }
}
```

After this class was recognised by Spring core it will use it as a Factory to get the instance of the service every time any other Spring bean need it. You don't need to call any kind of `get` method like in your factory. Spring is doing it automatically.

```java
@Service
public class SomeService {

    private final SentimentClient firstClient;

    @Autowired
    private SomeService(SentimentClient firstClient) {
        this.firstClient = firstClient;
    }

    // Some business logic here 
}
```

Worth to mention that the name of the factory method in Spring configuration is the name of the bean (service) created by this method and this name with class type is used to find the needed bean for Autowiring.

Comment: How is Spring going to find the beans by name in your example? The bean declaration is `firstClient`, the autowire parameter name is `firstService`.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've accepted an answer but I just want to provide my own opinion. The first thing is that I don't think you want to use Abstract Factory pattern, it seems that you're not creating the objects but just want to locate client objects based on their name. That's the job for Locator, let's call it ClientLocator (for lack of better name).

The idea is that you create a class called `ClientLocator` that implements `ApplicationContextAware`. By implementing this interface, Spring will inject an `ApplicationContext` object via a setter method. Using the `ApplicationContext` object, we can look for a bean by its name, afterwards we can check the type of the bean to make sure we get the correct one, and throw error when we don't.

Here's how the code looks.

**Clients**

```java
// SentimentClient.java
public interface SentimentClient {

    void call();

}


// FirstClient.java
@Service
public class FirstClient implements SentimentClient {


    @Override
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Hello from the first client");
    }
}

// SecondClient.java
@Service
public class SecondClient implements SentimentClient {

    @Override
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Hello from the second client");
    }
}
```

**ClientLocator.java**

```java
@Component
public class ClientLocator implements ApplicationContextAware {


    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public SentimentClient get(String name) {
        return ctx.getBean(name + "Client", SentimentClient.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

Here is how we can use the locator.

**ClientLocatorDemo.java**

```java
@Component
public class ClientLocatorDemo implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ClientLocator clientLocator;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        SentimentClient firstClient = clientLocator.get("first");
        SentimentClient secondClient = clientLocator.get("second");

        firstClient.call();
        secondClient.call();

        // output:
        // Hello from the first client
        // Hello from the second client
    }
}
```

By doing this way, anytime a code wants to get a client by its name, just autowire the `ClientLocator` and call the `get(String name)` method.

And the most important thing is that you can create client implementation as many as you like and get them by their name (assuming each has unique name and ends with 'Client') without having to autowire them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider following practices to apply the best practices:

1. Don't tightly couple object fields, rather inject those. This will allow changing the object field class as and when required.
2. To fulfill 1st point, always work by contract i.e. use interfaces.
3. Decide whether you want singletons or new object every time you call factory.
4. Maintainability of the abstract factory.

In your case you  have already adhered to #2.  For rest,
a) create beans for `FirstClient` and `SecondClient`.

b)If these has to be singleton as apparent from final keyword but not apparent by factory class, make both client classes singleton.

c) Rather than having string clientName, create an enum as it's more maintainable and secure as you always look up for well defined values.

d) Get rid of if-else and rather use a Map which is populated as post-construct of your factory. This will speed up getting the beans.

e) You can also think of Lazy initialization :).

```
class SentimentFactoryImpl{
    private Map<Client, SentimentClient> factoryMap; 
    @Autowired
    private final FirstClient first;
    @Autowired
    private final SecondClient second;



    @Override
    public SentimentClient get(String clientName) {
       Client Client.getByName(clientName);
     if(!factoryMap.contains(client)){
         throw new UnknownClientException("Service doesn't provide support for client: " 
         + clientName);
      }
       return factoryMap.get(Clients.getByName(clientName));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the reason I used String names instead of enumerators was to decouple my modules. So I have an getClientNames method in the Abstract Factory interface that returns a String[ ] and therefore it doesn't need to know or update the enumerator. This of course comes with the sacrifice of type safety, but with a good suite of unit tests it can be covered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say this class is annotated as `@Service`, I assume you'd like both clients to be autowired to it, and that they are both beans as well.

In that case, you can either autowire them in the constructor (in that case, the constructor should be public). Alternatively, you can do without constructor, and autowire the fields directly (or through setter methods)- this is less recommended, the better practice is to autowire using a constructor.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, "the constructor should be public": Idealistically yes, but I don't think that it is absolutely required, because internally uses reflection to create its instance, and even having a private constructor works

Comment: I think spring will support it, but not ideal for unit testing and other usages

Comment: @NirLevy can you explain why autowiring the fields directly is less recommended?